# There is any logs/journaling gem for ActiveRecord classes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, logging, rubygems

I'm looking for some gem, that will track on all the changes on ActiveRecord objects and will log them on some logs table.

Comment: http://www.nextgenerationseo.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/dad-google-facebook.jpg

Comment: My bad, https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/projects/audited

Answer (score 2):

Take a look `PaperTrail` gem, this gem lets you track changes to your models' data

https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail

Comment: Thanks, I've also found:
https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited